# Windows 10 Insider Preview wants to update but won't

Tags: windows-10, arm, windows-insider

I upgraded from an Intel Mac to an Apple Silicon Mac. For years I have been using a Windows 10 VM to run Dragon on my Mac. Upon transferring, I discovered that my old VM is incompatible, and I had to build a new one. Well, I'd really rather not go through the user interface change from Windows 10 to Windows 11, so I found a Windows Insider build of Windows 10 that would run on an ARM platform.

Unfortunately, what I found is outdated and reminds me of that fact several times a day. Advice found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/build-expiration says that I should do

> Settings > Update & Security > Windows Insider Program

but when I do, and click "Get started", I always get this:
[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure there is a Microsoft ARM Windows 10 Preview?   I do not think so.  Windows 10 will be dead in a year or so and Microsoft is putting only minimal effort into maintaining it.

Comment: An Insider Windows 10 might not still have an update. Note that the differences in Windows 11 and 10 user interface are mostly cosmetic, and third-party software can make it almost identical to Windows 10.